Reference request for Bessel function of the second kind with matrix argument
As the title says, I would like to know if anyone could provide a reference which provides the definition and properties of the Bessel function of the second kind with matrix argument. If possible, I would appreciate as well any reference which provides its power series.

I thought the way to give meaning to a function with a square matrix argument is to assume the function is replaced by its power series.  A square matrix raised to positive powers is well defined.
